# Badge for achieving a positive score for 30 consecutive days?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Is there any badge for achieving a positive score (at least one up-vote for a question or answer) for 30 consecutive days?

If there is a badge for this achievement, that would be good. If not, adding that feature would be nice to have.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Badges are there to encourage behaviour that people may not otherwise undertake but which benefits the site. In what way would your badge encourage people in that regard? Surely most people are already trying to get upvotes.

Comment: It will increase time spent by experts in stackoverflow site, which in-turn helps others, who are waiting for answers. Bad answers any way will be down-voted and experts does not post low quality posts to just get up-votes. More quality time on each day will result in more good answers and it will benefit community.

Comment: You get a badge if you get upvotes for 30 consecutive hours...